# How to return an object with the biggest collections size in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

For example, I have this code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Foo")
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String fooName;

@ElementCollection
private Set<Long> fooSet = new HashSet<Long>();

// constructors + getters

}
```

I want to create a method in my service class which will return an object with the greatest `fooSet` size. How can I achieve this with JPQL? The below code is incorrect but this is what I've tried to do:

```
@Override
public Foo getTopFoo() {
return (Foo)entityManager.createQuery("select c from Foo where max(size(c.fooSet)) ").getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: You can't get *an object* with the greatest `fooSet` size, but you can *a value* of the greatest fooSet size and then get *objects*  which have that fooSet size.

Comment: Also, note that you can have many objects with the bigest fooSet size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try that, because I know you can do subquery like in/= in JPQL, but I have big doubt that it works or that it's a valid syntax (notice the use of `Foo.class` to avoid the cast!):

```
@Override
public Foo getTopFoo() {
  return entityManager.createQuery("select c from Foo c where size(c.fooSet) = (select max(size(c.fooSet)) from Foo c)", Foo.class).getSingleResult();
}
```

I don't think that your JPA implementation will correctly translate the `max(size())` as it is a computed value: in pseudo SQL, it would give this:

```
select f.*, count(ff.*) as cu
from Foo f
left join Foo_fooSet ff on [...]
group by f.*
```

Of course, you need to enumerate all the column of table `Foo` (or `f`).

You would need to return a subquery based on that count, something like:

```
select max(cu) from (
    select f.*, count(ff.*) as cu
    from Foo f
    left join Foo_fooSet ff on [...]
    group by f.*
)
```

But I don't remember JPQL allowing a `from` that accepts a subquery.

However, you can use native query and this would work:

```
select f.*
from Foo f
left join Foo_fooSet ff on [...]
group by f.*
having count(ff.*) = (
  select max(cu) from (
    select f.id, count(ff.*) as cu
    from Foo f
      left join Foo_fooSet ff on [...]
    group by f.id
  )
)
```

In the the subquery (which count), you need only the id.

If the first `select` (f.*), you have to put ALL the column corresponding to the fields of your entity. Have fun!

Or: returns the id of your entity, then load them using your `entityManager`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and a coherent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most readable way to do this is using two queries.

`select id, count(*) from Bar group by id order by count(*) desc, id asc`

This query will give you the ids and the collection size (assuming `Bar` is the name of the collection table.

With JPA you can easily [select only the first result](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)). With that id, selecting the `Foo` object is easy.

Another option is to limit the result in SQL and join with the Foo table.

`from Foo where id = (select top 1 id from (select id, count(*) from Bar group by id, order by count(*) desc, id asc))`

This cannot be done in a db agnostic way, however.

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to be on the right track, you just need subqueries to return the max value and compare it to the size of the current c's list.  Something like:

So if `"Select max(size(c.fooSet)) from Foo c"` gives you the max value,

```
"select f from Foo f where size(f.fooSet) = (select max(size(c.fooSet)) from Foo c)"
```

Should give you the Foos with the size equal to the max size.